# How can I make this text label move to a new touch position and delete the old label in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I need the following to happen:

When I click, "Move" appears at the location of the click.(Works)

When I click again: The old "Move" goes away, new "Move" appears at the new location.(Doesn't work).

This is my current code:

```
void MainGame::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* pEvent)
{
   CCSetIterator itr;
   CCLabelTTF* labelMove = CCLabelTTF::create("Move", "Arial", 24);
   removeChild(labelMove);
   for(itr = pTouches->begin(); itr!=pTouches->end(); itr++)
   {
       CCTouch* thisTouch = (CCTouch*)*itr;
       CCPoint labelPosition = thisTouch->getLocation();
       labelMove->setPosition(labelPosition);
       addChild(labelMove);
   }
}
```

At the moment all that happens is that a new "Move" appears on screen at the click location each time, but the old ones all stay on screen. Should having "removeChild(labelMove)" not delete the old label before the new one is created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

its better if you create this label outside the cctouchesbegan method. In that case you don't have to remove child every time user touches the screen... you just update its location.

If you cannot do that I suggest you give a tag to the label and then remove child by tag... like this..

```
void MainGame::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* pEvent)
{
   CCSetIterator itr;
   removeChildByTag(1);

   CCLabelTTF* labelMove = CCLabelTTF::create("Move", "Arial", 24);
labelMove->setTag(1);
   for(itr = pTouches->begin(); itr!=pTouches->end(); itr++)
   {
       CCTouch* thisTouch = (CCTouch*)*itr;
       CCPoint labelPosition = thisTouch->getLocation();
       labelMove->setPosition(labelPosition);
       addChild(labelMove);
   }
}
```